# Camera walks through the wall built in blender

Tags: physics, collision, blender, aframe

My camera simply walks through interior walls of a house I built in Blender. Here are the steps I followed -

1. Modelled a house in Blender.
2. Applied physics -> collision to interior and the exterior walls of the house
3. Exported as .obj and .mtl and used it in a-frame
4. Placed the camera inside the house.
5. While the camera is able to walk out of the house from inside by walking through walls, it is unable to move back into the house from outside as collision occurs. Also, camera is able to walk through all the interior walls of the house without collision.
6. I am not sure how to share my blender files.

Here is my code -

```
<div id="myEmbeddedScene">
    <a-scene raycaster-autorefresh physics embedded="">

        <a-assets>
          <a-asset-item id="house-obj" src="../images/house.obj"></a-asset-item>
          <a-asset-item id="house-mtl" src="../images/house.mtl"></a-asset-item>
          <a-mixin id="checkpoint"></a-mixin>
          <a-mixin id="checkpoint-hovered" color="#6CEEB5"></a-mixin>
        </a-assets>

      <!-- Player -->
        <a-entity camera="userHeight: 0.6"
            universal-controls="movementControls: checkpoint, keyboard"
            checkpoint-controls="mode: animate"
            kinematic-body>
            <a-cursor
                  cursor="fuse: true;"
                  timeout="10"
                  position="0 0.1 -3"
                  geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.02; radiusOuter: 0.03;"
                  material="color: #4CC3D9; shader: flat;">
            </a-cursor>
        </a-entity>


        <!-- Ground -->
        <a-grid static-body visible="false"></a-grid>

        <!-- Obstacles -->
        <a-obj-model src="#house-obj" mtl="#house-mtl" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5" rotation="0 0 0" class="clickable" static-body></a-obj-model>




      <!-- Lighting -->
      <a-light type="ambient" color="#bbb"></a-light>
    <!--  <a-light color="#ccc" position="0 30 0" distance="100" intensity="0.4" type="point"></a-light>
      <a-light color="#ccc" position="3 10 -10" distance="50" intensity="0.4" type="point"></a-light> -->

    </a-scene>

</div>

My codepen - https://codepen.io/nirajupadhyay11/pen/ZaGWdN
```

Answer (score 1):

https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/introduction/faq.html#can-i-prevent-the-camera-from-going-through-obstacles

> For non-VR desktop experiences with a gamepad or keyboard controls or for VR scenes where the camera is inside a vehicle, you can add a physics engine to prevent movement through obstacles.

https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is what I am trying to achieve - https://archviz-demo.surge.sh/   I tried both applying a "rigid body" as well as a-frame physics on the model that I built in Blender but the camera keeps going through the interior walls of the house.